# Filtering occurrences in a json object array

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a large JSON file with this structure:

```
[
    {
       "sniffer_serial":"7c9ebd9448a0",
       "serial":"086bd7c39c8c",
       "temp":31.36,
       "x":-0.484375,
       "y":-0.0078125,
       "z":-0.859375,
       "rssi":-70,
       "id":33069,
       "date":"2021-07-14 15:45:54.411"
    },
    {
        "sniffer_serial":"7c9ebd945194",
        "serial":"086bd7c39c8c",
        "temp":31.36,
        "x":-0.484375,
        "y":-0.0078125,
        "z":-0.859375,
        "rssi":-70,
        "id":33069,
        "date":"2021-07-14 15:45:54.414"
     },
     {
        "sniffer_serial":"7c9ebd9448a0",
        "serial":"086bd7c39c8c",
        "temp":31.36,
        "x":-0.484375,
        "y":-0.0078125,
        "z":-0.859375,
        "rssi":-70,
        "id":33069,
        "date":"2021-07-14 15:45:54.536"
     },
     {
        "sniffer_serial":"7c9ebd945194",
        "serial":"086bd7c39c8c",
        "temp":31.36,
        "x":-0.484375,
        "y":-0.0078125,
        "z":-0.859375,
        "rssi":-70,
        "id":33069,
        "date":"2021-07-14 15:45:54.539"
     },
     {
        "sniffer_serial":"7c9ebd9448a0",
        "serial":"086bd7c39c8c",
        "temp":31.36,
        "x":-0.484375,
        "y":-0.0078125,
        "z":-0.859375,
        "rssi":-70,
        "id":33069,
        "date":"2021-07-14 15:45:54.661"
     },
     {
        "sniffer_serial":"7c9ebd945194",
        "serial":"086bd7c39c8c",
        "temp":31.36,
        "x":-0.484375,
        "y":-0.0078125,
        "z":-0.859375,
        "rssi":-70,
        "id":33069,
        "date":"2021-07-14 15:45:54.664"
     },
     {
        "date": "2021-07-13/10:28:00.930",
        "id": 21661,
        "rssi": -81,
        "serial": "086bd7c39baf",
        "sniffer_serial": "7c9ebd9448a0",
        "temp": 36.21,
        "x": -0.4453125,
        "y": -0.1328125,
        "z": -0.8671875
    },
    {
        "date": "2021-07-13/10:28:01.680",
        "id": 21663,
        "rssi": -80,
        "serial": "086bd7c39baf",
        "sniffer_serial": "7c9ebd9448a0",
        "temp": 36.21,
        "x": -0.4140625,
        "y": -0.1171875,
        "z": -0.8515625
    },
    {
        "date": "2021-07-13/10:28:02.60",
        "id": 21664,
        "rssi": -88,
        "serial": "086bd7c39baf",
        "sniffer_serial": "7c9ebd9450cc",
        "temp": 36.21,
        "x": -0.4375,
        "y": -0.0546875,
        "z": -0.8515625
    }
 ]
```

As you can see, I have somewhat repeating values.
The `id` 33069 is repeated 6 times, that's 3 times for each `sniffer_serial`, with only the timestamp varying between them.

What I'm wondering is keep the first three occurrences of the same id and descard the other three.

On this example, this repeating pattern only appeared once, but it can happen multiple times throughout the file.

What I got so far is how to keep only the first occurrence of each `id` and append it to a list.

```
loader = json.loads(myJsonFile)
data = []
for key, items in groupby(sorted(loader, key=lambda x: (x['serial'], x['date'])), key=lambda x: x['id']):
            data.append(next(items))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe keeping a dictionary of the count might help here. Here's a solution I tried out.

```py
data = []
count_book = {}
for i in loader:
    if i['id'] not in count_book:
        count_book[i['id']] = 0
    if count_book[i['id']] < 3:
        data.append(i)
        count_book[i['id']] += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `defaultdict`

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict 
>>> data = defaultdict(list)
>>> for x in loader:
...   if len(data[x['id']]) < 3:
...     data[x['id']].append(x)
...
>>> data
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {33069: [{'sniffer_serial': '7c9ebd9448a0', 'serial': '086bd7c39c8c', 'temp': 31.36, 'x': -0.484375, 'y': -0.0078125, 'z': -0.859375, 'rssi': -70, 'id': 33069, 'date': '2021-07-14 15:45:54.411'}, {'sniffer_serial': '7c9ebd945194', 'serial': '086bd7c39c8c', 'temp': 31.36, 'x': -0.484375, 'y': -0.0078125, 'z': -0.859375, 'rssi': -70, 'id': 33069, 'date': '2021-07-14 15:45:54.414'}, {'sniffer_serial': '7c9ebd9448a0', 'serial': '086bd7c39c8c', 'temp': 31.36, 'x': -0.484375, 'y': -0.0078125, 'z': -0.859375, 'rssi': -70, 'id': 33069, 'date': '2021-07-14 15:45:54.536'}, {'sniffer_serial': '7c9ebd945194', 'serial': '086bd7c39c8c', 'temp': 31.36, 'x': -0.484375, 'y': -0.0078125, 'z': -0.859375, 'rssi': -70, 'id': 33069, 'date': '2021-07-14 15:45:54.539'}, {'sniffer_serial': '7c9ebd9448a0', 'serial': '086bd7c39c8c', 'temp': 31.36, 'x': -0.484375, 'y': -0.0078125, 'z': -0.859375, 'rssi': -70, 'id': 33069, 'date': '2021-07-14 15:45:54.661'}, {'sniffer_serial': '7c9ebd945194', 'serial': '086bd7c39c8c', 'temp': 31.36, 'x': -0.484375, 'y': -0.0078125, 'z': -0.859375, 'rssi': -70, 'id': 33069, 'date': '2021-07-14 15:45:54.664'}], 21661: [{'date': '2021-07-13/10:28:00.930', 'id': 21661, 'rssi': -81, 'serial': '086bd7c39baf', 'sniffer_serial': '7c9ebd9448a0', 'temp': 36.21, 'x': -0.4453125, 'y': -0.1328125, 'z': -0.8671875}], 21663: [{'date': '2021-07-13/10:28:01.680', 'id': 21663, 'rssi': -80, 'serial': '086bd7c39baf', 'sniffer_serial': '7c9ebd9448a0', 'temp': 36.21, 'x': -0.4140625, 'y': -0.1171875, 'z': -0.8515625}], 21664: [{'date': '2021-07-13/10:28:02.60', 'id': 21664, 'rssi': -88, 'serial': '086bd7c39baf', 'sniffer_serial': '7c9ebd9450cc', 'temp': 36.21, 'x': -0.4375, 'y': -0.0546875, 'z': -0.8515625}]})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of `pandas` to read the json file, perform a `groupby` on id and then keep only the first 3 rows in this way:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json('...') # json file directory
df = df.groupby('id').nth((0,1,2)).reset_index()

df.to_json("...", orient='records') # to save the result as json
```